# Refactor ViewControllers - Error : Storyboard both contain a view controller with same identifier

Tags: xcode, swift, compiler-errors, storyboard, xcode7

I am using Xcode 7.3 for a project (minimum deployment target 8.0)

I have a storyboard that is growing in size. I thought of refactoring two (2) groups of scenes into Two (2) different storyboards using **Editor -> Refactor To Storyboard...** then creating two storyboards with different names to 'hold' the respective refactored scenes.

It worked as expected - two new storyboards (NewStoryBoard1 & NewStoryBoard2) that 'held' the two groups of refactored scenes.

When I build the project I get this error:

> Deploying Storyboard References to iOS 8.0 requires that your
>   storyboards do not share any view controller identifiers.
>   NewStoryBoard1.storyboard and NewStoryBoard2.storyboard both contain a
>   view controller with identifier "UIViewController-knd-7b-mzO".

I did not name the identifiers as

> UIViewController-knd-7b-mzO

this seemingly was done automatically in Xcode.

My question is, why is Xcode creating two storyboard references to two different view controllers with the same identifiers?

I have a few similar Q&A threads that discuss this problem, but they have offered no solution.

How can I best fix this issue? Many thanks.

**MORE INFO**

After trying to refactor my selected scenes/views, I was presented with a new storyboard like this:

[image]

Zooming in:

[image]

An odd storyboard reference presented itself - despite the fact that I had already selected one ViewController on the new storyboard as my `Initial ViewController`.

I got the same type of storyboard reference in two of my new refactored storyboards. As a result, I received this error when I built the project:

> Deploying Storyboard References to iOS 8.0 requires that your
>   storyboards do not share any view controller identifiers.
>   NewStoryBoard1.storyboard and NewStoryBoard2.storyboard both contain a
>   view controller with identifier "UIViewController-knd-7b-mzO".

I tried renaming the new storyboard reference (listed as "Issue" in my diagram above) but that did not resolve the error.

Please see my answer below for how I resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I received the random `UIViewController-knd-7b-mzO` duplicate storyboard references that caused me my build error because:

> Note: If a scene has an empty storyboard ID, the Refactor to
>   Storyboard command automatically generates an ugly one, such as
>   UIViewController-gtY-c7-gYu.

(source) https://www.raywenderlich.com/115697/ios-9-storyboards-tutorial-whats-new-in-storyboards

And I had not entered storyboard IDs for all my refactored scenes/views.

Moving on ... I managed to resolve the error issue by:

1. Deleting the oddly-placed storyboard reference (listed in my above question as "Issue");
2. Making sure that I had specified an `Initial ViewController` in each new storyboard; and
3. Making sure the `Reference ID` field of both 'new storyboard' references in my **Main** (i.e. original) storyboard were **blank**.

[image]

In effect, this made sense. The reference directs any calls on the refactored storyboard scenes to the new storyboard (referenced by the `Storyboard` field) and thus automatically presenting the respective 'new' `Initial ViewControllers`.

Apologies for any errors in my syntax or code references, I am new to programming.

I do hope this helps anyone who may face the same issue in future.